# Post curl data with php

Tags: php, curl

I have a dashboard which I post data to display on.The dashbaord has multiple segments.
I have an sql query which retrieves the data and loops through to push results. I want run the curl command below via php within this script. Can someone point me in the right direction? Or help. I have looked around a bit but im confused on how to get it to work.

Below is the what my php page will generate and this is what i would like to send via php using curl.

```
    curl -d '{ "auth_token" : "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN" , "value" : "519" }' http://172.21.4.62:3030/widgets/Skin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without any additional classes:

> ```
>    $ch = curl_init('http://172.21.4.62:3030/widgets/Skin');
>    $curlOptions = array(
>         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
>         CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] => true,
>         CURLOPT_POST => true,
>         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("auth_token" => "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN", "value" => "519"),
>     );
>    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);
>    $response = curl_exec($ch);
>    curl_close($ch);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use any curl class, f.e. [curl.class.php](https://github.com/lepunk/curl.class.php)

Usage:

```
$curl = new Curl();

$data = array("auth_token" => "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN", "value" => "519");

$page = $curl->post("YOUR_URL_TO_CALL_VIA_CURL", $data);
```